# sql:invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: This is the Image.]

The data is classified so that I could only upload a picture. Sorry about that.
The sql statement comes up with "invalid number", I think it is probably wrong in the first line `to_number(2016-(substr(cust_no,8,4)))`, the `cust_no` is `varchar2(25)`, how could I fix it? Thank you

Comment: What RDBMS are you running this SQL statement against?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please read [ask]. We don't care about the actual data, we only need enough data so that we can reproduce the problem, and it can be totally made up.

Comment: Unless you provide some example )not necessary actual, but at least provide the formatting and some fake versions of it) of what your customer number could contain, we can do very little to help

Comment: thank you for you advice.the RDBMS is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Oracle, but it looks to my like you do something like

```
to_number('2016' - '5')
```

that's an expression that doesn't make any sense - minus is not defined on a string - unless Oracle does the conversion implicitly, in which case I don't understand why you use to_number at all. You'd probably need to do

```
to_number('2016') - to_number('5') instead.
```

Otherwise, there is at least one occurrence of alphanumeric data in what you think is an always-numeric customer-number.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT 2016-to_number(substr(cust_no,8,4)) FROM dual;
```